# Can a custom NSURLProtocol intercept traffic from other apps if its running in the background?

Tags: ios

If an NSURLProtocol derived class registers to handle http, then if the app is running in the background (using didBeginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, or a voip/location background mode), then will it be aware of any http traffic from other apps?

I presume not, but I'd like to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it shouldn't do. It will only be involved with the traffic you have previously set.
A HTTP connection essentially uses sockets as a base layer. These are only concerned with the connections they have made, not with others.